# i don't know why happens this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

my code in python have this error, i'm listen python and don't know why happens, in the console the python interpreter print this:

```
Introdusca el titulo del libro> crisal
introdusca el autor del libro> roijari
introdusca la editorial del libro> tor 
introdusca el precio del libro> 456
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/crisal/programas-en-python/tadcomp_clase3.py", line 32, in <module>
   cargar_en_libreria(lr,l)
 File "/home/crisal/programas-en-python/tad_comp_libre.py", line 10, in cargar_en_libreria
   libreria.append(libro)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

the problem happens when import the funtion that load the data in abstact data type(ADT) in the list that is allocated in the ADT with the name  'tad_comp_libre' and the code in python is this(main):

```
## EJERCICIO PRACTICO ##

#cargar cuatro libros

#imprimir los datos de todo los libros

#eliminar el 2º libro

#imprimir libros restantes

# estructura intrer de los libros
## nombre
## editorial
## autor
## precio
from tad_libro import*
from tad_comp_libre import*

#creo un for carador de los libro
l=crear_libro() #crea los libros
lr=crear_libreria() #crea la libreria
    
#introdusco los datos que van a tener los libros y los pone en la libreria
for i in range(0,3):
    nom=input("Introdusca el titulo del libro> ")
    aut=input("introdusca el autor del libro> ")
    edi=input("introdusca la editorial del libro> ")
    prec=float(input("introdusca el precio del libro> "))

    cargar_libro(l,nom,aut,edi,prec)
    cargar_en_libreria(lr,l)

    
#imprime los datos de los libros
for i in range(0,tamanio(lr)):
    b_l=buscar_libro(lr,i)
    print("--------------------------\n")
    print("titulo: ",Vernombre(l))
    print("autor: ",Verautor(l))
    print("Ediorial: ",Vereditorial(l))
    print("Precio: ",Verprecio(l))
    print("--------------------------\n")

    

opc=1
##elimino el segundo libro:
opc=int(input("desea eliminar un libro?: Si(1)/No(0)>>"))
while opc==1:
    nom=input("elija el libro que desea eliminar(nombre)")

    b_l=buscar_libro2(lr,nom)
          
    borrar_libro(lr,b_l)
    
    opc=int(input("desea eliminar otro libro?: Si(1)/No(0)>>"))
else:
    print("se a terminado el proceso de eliinacion de libros")

#imprime de nuevo la lista
for i in lr:
    print("--------------------------\n")
    print("titulo: ",Vernombre(i))
    print("autor: ",Verautor(i))
    print("Ediorial: ",Vereditoria(i))
    print("Precio: ",Verprecio(i))
    print("--------------------------\n")
```

(tad_libro)

```
def crear_libro():
    libro=["","","",0]
    return libro
    

def cargar_libro(libro,n,a,e,p):

    libro[0]=n
    libro[1]=a
    libro[2]=e
    libro[3]=p

def Vernombre(libro):
    return libro[0]

def Verautor(libro):
    return libro[1]

def Vereditorial(libro):
    return libro[2]

def Verprecio(libro):
    return libro[3]

def modifNom(libro,nom1):
    libro[0]=nom1

def modifaut(libro,aut1):
    libro[1]=aut1

def modifpre(libro,pre1):
    libro[2]=pre1
```

(tad_comp_libre)
in this ADT happens the problem when load the data

```
from tad_libro import*


#crea el tipo de dato libreria 
def crear_libreria():
    libreria=[]

#carga los datos de los libros en la libreia
def cargar_en_libreria(libreria,libro):
    libreria.append(libro)

#libro elimina un libro puntual de la libreria
def borrar_libro(libreria,l):
    libreria.remove(l)

#devuelve el tamanio de la libreria
def tamanio(libreria):
    return len(libreria)

#busca un libro dentro de la libreria
def buscar_libro(libreria,i):
    return libreria[i]

def bucar_libro2(libreria,nombre):
    for i in libreia:# el parametro libreria transforma el indice de tipo tad_libro porque es el tipo de dato que hay alojado en libreria
        if Vernombre(i)==nombre:
            return i
```

if you can help my, i'm will really thanks they, sorry for the code in spanish

Answer (score 3):

`crear_libreria` needs to return its result.  Right now, it stored in a variable that is immediately destroyed.  As a result, the `lr` global is set to None.

Do this:

```
#crea el tipo de dato libreria 
def crear_libreria():
    return []
```